# How to parse Soap Envelope in Golang ?

Tags: soap, go, nusoap

I am new to golang and Soap and having trouble in parsing soap msg.

1.I have an Soap message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soap:Body>
<activationPack_completeResponse"http://tempuri.org/">
<activationPack_completeResult xsi:type="xsd:string">Active</activationPack_completeResult>
</activationPack_completeResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now how should i Unmarshal them in golang what should be my struct declaration for tag Soap Envelope.

I have some structure as below:

```
type MyRespEnvelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope"`
    Soap    *Body
}
type Body struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`
    GetResponse *ActivationPack_CompleteResponse
}
type ActivationPack_CompleteResponse struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"activationPack_completeResponse"`
    Id      string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    MyVar   string   `xml:"activationPack_completeResult"`
}
```

But I am getting error as below:

```
error: expected element <Envelope> in name space http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ but have soap*stopped,reason="end-stepping-range",frame={addr="0x0000000000401211",func="main.UnmarshalFirstDitto",args=[{name="data",value="\"\\nNotice: Undefined variable: area in /var/www/nusoap/dittotv.php on line 25\\n\\nNotice: Undefined variable: area in /var/www/nusoap/dittotv.php on line 27\\n\\nNotice: Undefined variable: area in /var/www/nu\"..."}],file="/media/winshare/Golang/WorkSpace/src/DittoTv/ditto.go",fullname="/media/winshare/Golang/WorkSpace/src/DittoTv/ditto.go",line="60"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="0"
```

So someone please tell me how should i declare my structure so that i am able to parse the soap message.

Comment: Are you sure the document you're trying to parse is actually XML?  The error message makes it sound like you are trying to parse a (non-XML) error from a PHP script

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Yes i am. But for my knowledge what field make you feel that php is returning error

Comment: Part of the error reads `args=[{name="data",value="\"\\nNotice: Undefined variable: area in /var/www/nusoap/dittotv.php on line 25\\n...`

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Ok let me check it once

Comment: @JamesHenstridge You were right i have fixed the same in my php script but even now i am getting approximate same error

Comment: My resp Xml Mobile Number is string type
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><soap:Body><activationPack_completeResponse"http://tempuri.org/"><activationPack_completeResult xsi:type="xsd:string">9650104435</activationPack_completeResult></activationPack_completeResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Error Received:
error: expected element <Envelope> in name space http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ but have soap*stopped,reason="end-stepping-range",frame={addr="0x0000000000401211",func="main.UnmarshalFirstDitto",args=[{name="data",value="\"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?><soap:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\\\" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\\" xmlns:xsd=\\\"http://www\"..."}]

Comment: @JamesHenstridge ,file="/media/winshare/Golang/WorkSpace/src/DittoTv/ditto.go",fullname="/media/winshare/Golang/WorkSpace/src/DittoTv/ditto.go",line="60"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="0"

Comment: Is there an `xmlns:soap` attribute on the top level `<soap:Envelope>` element?  I don't see it on the sample message in the question, and it is required for the document to parse correctly.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge No but there is xmlns:SOAP-ENV field which is generated by nusoap in PHP

Comment: That's not how XML namespaces work.  In order to use the `soap:` prefix on elements and attributes, there must be an `xmlns:soap` attribute binding the prefix to a namespace URI.  The `xmlns:SOAP-ENV` attribute would let you use e.g. `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`.  Perhaps try feeding the document to the `xmllint` tool to verify that it is valid.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I have modified nusoap.php And my xml response is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><activationPack_completeResponse"http://tempuri.org/"><activationPack_completeResult xsi:type="xsd:string">9650104435</activationPack_completeResult></activationPack_completeResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: @JamesHenstridge 
But now i am getting following error
error: XML syntax error on line 1: expected attribute name in element*stopped,reason="end-stepping-range",frame={addr="0x0000000000401026",func="main.FirstDitto",args=[],file="/media/winshare/Golang/WorkSpace/src/DittoTv/ditto.go",fullname="/media/winshare/Golang/WorkSpace/src/DittoTv/ditto.go",line="52"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="0"

I am new to php soap and golang please help

Comment: Have you tried running the document through `xmllint` to see if it is actually valid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Your XML was malformed, I assume it's a bad copy-paste. I corrected it, line 4: `<activationPack_completeResponse"http://tempuri.org/">` -> `<activationPack_completeResponse Id="http://tempuri.org/">`
2. Your types were wrong. in `MyRespEnvelope`you call the `Body` struct `Soap`. Without defining its xml name you're not going to get anything. An easier fix is to change the name from `Soap` to `Body`.
3. I'm not an expert in XML, but I think you were doing something wrong with namespaces.
   simplifying your types a little, here is a working example: http://play.golang.org/p/957GWzfdvN

   ```
   package main

   import "fmt"
   import "encoding/xml"

   type MyRespEnvelope struct {
       XMLName xml.Name
       Body    Body
   }

   type Body struct {
       XMLName     xml.Name
       GetResponse completeResponse `xml:"activationPack_completeResponse"`
   }

   type completeResponse struct {
       XMLName xml.Name `xml:"activationPack_completeResponse"`
       Id      string   `xml:"Id,attr"`
       MyVar   string   `xml:"activationPack_completeResult"`
   }

   func main() {

       Soap := []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soap:Body>
   <activationPack_completeResponse Id="http://tempuri.org/">
   <activationPack_completeResult xsi:type="xsd:string">Active</activationPack_completeResult>
   </activationPack_completeResponse>
   </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>`)

       res := &MyRespEnvelope{}
       err := xml.Unmarshal(Soap, res)

       fmt.Println(res.Body, err)
   }
   ```

   Note: In the code I put together, I don't use pointer to structs but the structs themselves. You can use either depending on how you're intending to use it, and your preferences I guess.